# Change Swagger UI request URL when I tap to "Execute" button

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jvm, swagger, swagger-ui

I deployed my app on AWS. Also, I configured Nginx that `/api` prefix (`https://mywebsitename.com/api`) will be automatically redirected to `https://127.0.0.1:8080/`.

Every HTTP request & response works perfectly.

Also, I added the swagger library to my app, with following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    fun api(): Docket {
        return Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
    }
}
```

I use this two libraries:

```
implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2")
implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2")
```

Everything works perfectly locally.

The problem is:
The swagger link (https://mywebsitename.com/api/swagger-ui.html) works perfectly, and everything is shown. But, when I tap to the "Try it out" button and make "Execute", it returns me `TypeError: Failed to fetch`. It happens because the request goes to `https://127.0.0.1:8080/some_endpoint`.

Question is: How I can configure my spring boot app that when I tap to "Execute" button, the request will go to `https://mywebsitename.com/api/some_end_point`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding the [`host`](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/current/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html#host-java.lang.String-) call in the Swagger configuration like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    fun api(): Docket {
        return Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)

            .host("https://mywebsitename.com")

            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but request goes to Nginx and it returns me **301 Moved Permanently**

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding **servers** in Swagger Configuration like this:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    Server serverLocal = new Server("local", "http://localhost:8080", "for local usages", Collections.emptyList(), Collections.emptyList());
    Server testServer = new Server("test", "https://example.org", "for testing", Collections.emptyList(), Collections.emptyList());
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .servers(serverLocal, testServer)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```